# req.isAuthenticated() sometimes false when deployed to vercel

Tags: cookies, oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth, passport.js

My application works as expected when I run on my localhost.
But after deploying in vercel i counter this error.
When log in is successful and i see the secrets page, when i try to access the account page it becomes false. And when i reload the page after logging in, it redirect me to log in page. and when. But when i try to access the secrets page without logging in, req.authenticated is t
https://secret-website-nine.vercel.app/
website ^^^

```
//jshint esversion:6
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;
const FacebookStrategy = require("passport-facebook").Strategy;
const findOrCreate = require("mongoose-findorcreate");
//var LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.set("views", __dirname + "/views");
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);

app.enable("trust proxy");
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "Our little secret.",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    proxy: true,
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

const url = process.env.MONGO_URL;
mongoose
  .connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("connected to db");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(`error connected to db ${err}`);
  });

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
  googleId: String,
  facebookId: String,
  secrets: [
    {
      secret: String,
    },
  ],
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
userSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
  User.findById(id)
    .then((user) => {
      done(null, user);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      done(err, null);
    });
});

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: "https://secret-website-nine.vercel.app/auth/google/secrets",
      userProfileURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo",
    },
    async function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
      const info = profile._json;
      //console.log(profile._json);
      await User.findOrCreate(
        { username: info.email, googleId: info.sub },
        function (err, user) {
          if (err) {
            return cb(null, false);
          }

          return cb(err, user);
        }
      );
    }
  )
);

/* google get request */
app.get(
  "/auth/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile", "email"] })
);

app.get(
  "/auth/google/secrets",
  passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/duplicate" }),
  function (req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect to secrets.
    res.redirect("/secrets");
  }
);

// get and see user secrets
app.get("/secrets", async function (req, res) {
  console.log("secrets user " + req.user);
  console.log("secrets authen " + req.isAuthenticated());
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    const foundUsers = await User.find({
      secrets: { $exists: true, $not: { $size: 0 } },
    });
    //console.log(foundUsers)
    //.then( ()=>{
    res.render("secrets", { usersWithSecrets: foundUsers });

    /* })
   .catch( (err)=>{
       console.log(err) 
   })  */
  } else {
    res.redirect("/login");
  }
});

//see account
app.get("/account", async function (req, res) {
  console.log("submit user " + req.user);
  console.log("submit authen" + req.isAuthenticated());
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    const userId = await User.findById(req.user.id);
    // console.log("/submit " + userId);
    res.render("submit", { user: userId, wrong: "" });
  } else {
    res.redirect("/login");
  }
});
app.post("/login", function (req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate("local", async function (err, user, info) {
    //console.log("all" + err, user, info);
    if (err) {
      //console.log("err" + err);
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      //console.log("user " + err);
      const email = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }).lean();
      if (!email) {
        return res.render("login", { user: "email" });
      } else {
        return res.render("login", { user: "wrong" });
      }
    }
    req.logIn(user, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      //console.log(user);
      return res.redirect("/secrets");
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
//edit a secret
app.post("/edit", async function (req, res) {
  const editVal = req.body.secret;
  const delId = req.body.hisId;
  const secretId = req.body.del;
  //console.log(editVal);
  const a = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: delId, "secrets._id": secretId },
    {
      $set: { "secrets.$.secret": editVal },
    }
  );
  //console.log(a);
  res.redirect("/secrets");
});
```